# Objective-C Array Literal - Avoiding adding a nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

**With the new Objective-C array literal ...**

for (UIView *view_ in @[self.myView01, self.myView1, self.myView2]) {
        ...
}

**Occasionally one of the myView* objects is nil, which causes the error ...**

-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

**Question**

Is there a nice shortcut way of checking the 3 objects before adding them to the array?

Comment: Would setting your views to `NSNull` an option for you?

Answer (score 4):

To be clear, when you are using literals then you are not adding objects to an array, you are initializing an array. You could do:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    (self.myView01 ? self.myView01 : [NSNull null]),
    (self.myView1 ? self.myView1 : [NSNull null]),
    (self.myView2 ? self.myView2 : [NSNull null]),
];

for (UIView *view_ in array) {
    if (view_ != [NSNull null]) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

But then in your loop you'd have to compare each object you are iterating over to `[NSNull null]`. Alternatively, you could not use a literal and build a NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

if (self.myView01) {
    [array addObject:self.myView01];
}

if (self.myView1) {
    [array addObject:self.myView1];
}

if (self.myView2) {
    [array addObject:self.myView2];
}   

for (UIView *view_ in array) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

It really depends on what you think is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to check them before creating the array simply

```
  NSAssert (self.myView0 && self.myView1 && self.myView2);
```

works.  If you want to create the array even if one value is `nil` use:

```
   (self.myView0 ? self.myView0 : [NSNull null])
```